# Rails URL changing without view changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I am testing an app in Rails and having a failure I can't figure out. I have a table called "Families" with basic CRUD functionality. When creating a new "family" in the new view, if the title is not validated, the new view is supposed to be rendered again. And it is. But the URL changes from "families/new" to "families." The view and the URL do not match. And my test is failing as a result. Why is this happening in my URL? Here is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "Creating a family" do 

scenario "A user creates a family with invalid title" do 
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Create Family'
    click_button "Create"
    expect(page.current_path).to eq(new_family_path)
end

end
```

Here are the new and create actions in my controller:

```
def new 
    @family = Family.new
end 

def create 
    @family = Family.new(family_params)
    if @family.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else 
        flash.now[:danger] = "There was a problem"
        render :new
    end 
end
```

Family model:

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord

    validates :title, presence: true

end
```

Comment: The answers have pointed out what you're seeing is normal rails behavior, however you should also never be using `current_path` with the `eq` matcher since it defeats Capybara's waiting retrying behavior.  Instead use the `have_current_path` matcher -  `expect(page).to have_current_path(new_family_path)` . It will increase test stability greatly when you move to a JS capable driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right here:

```
def create 
  @family = Family.new(family_params)
  if @family.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    flash.now[:danger] = "There was a problem"
    render :new
  end 
end
```

When you hit the `create` action, you are `POST`ing to `families`. You then `render :new` - which leaves you at the `families` url with the `new` partial showing.

If you want to end up at the `families/new` url, you need to do something more like:

```
def create 
  @family = Family.new(family_params)
  if @family.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    flash.now[:danger] = "There was a problem"
    redirect_to new_family_path
  end 
end
```

Remember: rendering and routing are two separate things. Just because you `render :new` does not imply that you should end up at the `new_families_path` url. Two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The view is being rendered, however because you hit the POST endpoint `create` and then rendered `new`, the POST endpoint is what the url shows.

You probably don't want to change it to redirect to `new` here though, because you'll lose the data saved in your `@family` object which I am assuming you use to display the user input on the form.

I would advise you to instead check that the form is rendered on the page again or that the flash message is displayed, rather than confirming that the url is `/new`.